# How to replace default android keypad emoji icons with custom icons without using emoji keypad android?

Tags: android, emoji

I am working on chat application in which I need to display the emojis in chat messages.

To display images I am using supernova library [Super Nova Library](https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji) to display the emojis. But scroll is not smooth and too laggy. So I replaced the **"Emoji TextView"** to normal **"TextView"** and scroll working like charm.

Now the problem is : My Web team and iOS team are using icons in [Twitter Emoji Library](http://github.com/twitter/twemoji). So my plan is to replace the **Twitter Emoji Library** emoji's to the default emoji's in **Default Text View**. How can I override my custom emoji's in place of default TextView emoji's?

Comment: You are talking about scroll in *list-view/recylce-view* of messages, or scroll inside the *emoji keyboard*?